# Is there a way to detect which sim is used for cellular data on an android device with multiple sims?

Tags: android

I see that you can use the SubscriptionManager to get info on all of the sims on an android device (on Android 5.1 or later). Is there a way to know which sim is actually being used for cellular data? Is that only available using the SubscriptionManager.getDefaultDataSubscriptionId method added in N (API 24)?